# telegram group exchanging messages with bot

Tags: python-3.x

I hae been working on this code but i need help, so far is working,, basically the code needs the bot to take messages from group A, send to group B... when the user from group b reads the message and reply, the bot must take the message and reply the original message in group A with the response.. so far the bot copies the message from A and post it on B... and copies Every post from B to A... i just want to take the replies from B.. no every message is sent... can anyone help?

this is the code

import telebot
from config import * #importar el token
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from telegram import Update

## instance and token

updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

## dictionary to follow up conersations

conversaciones = {}

## handling group a

def manejar_mensaje_grupo_a(update, context):
message = update.message
conversaciones[message.message_id] = {'mensaje_a': message, 'mensaje_b': None}  # adding message A to dictionary
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=grupo_b_id, text=message.text)

## handling msg group b

def manejar_mensaje_grupo_b(update, context):
message = update.message
if message.reply_to_message and message.reply_to_message.forward_from_chat and message.reply_to_message.forward_from_chat.id == grupo_a_id:
conversacion = conversaciones.get(message.reply_to_message.message_id)
if conversacion:
conversacion['mensaje_b'] = message
if conversacion['mensaje_a'].reply_to_message:
reply_message_id = conversacion['mensaje_a'].reply_to_message.message_id
else:
reply_message_id = conversacion['mensaje_a'].message_id
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=grupo_a_id, text=message.text, reply_to_message_id=reply_message_id)

## creation fof dispatchers

dispatcher_grupo_a = updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.chat(chat_id=grupo_a_id), manejar_mensaje_grupo_a))
dispatcher_grupo_b = updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.chat(chat_id=grupo_b_id), manejar_mensaje_grupo_b))

## start bot

updater.start_polling()

I hae been working on this code but i need help, so far is working,, basically the code needs the bot to take messages from group A, send to group B... when the user from group b reads the message and reply, the bot must take the message and reply the original message in group A with the response.. so far the bot copies the message from A and post it on B... and copies Every post from B to A... i just want to take the replies from B.. no every message is sent... can anyone help?

Comment: Please use codeblocks to format your code correctly (use three backquotes (`) on the line before and the line after your code